# How to retrieve query parameter value from portlet render url in liferay?

Tags: java, portlet, liferay-6

I tried something like this:

```
 <%
    int startIndex = 3;

    %>
   <portlet:renderURL var="nextURL">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/portlet/ext/ctestportlet/view.jsp?st=      <%=startIndex%>" />

</portlet:renderURL>

<a href="<%=nextURL%>">Next</a>
```

And I am retrieving like this:

```
<%
   String startIndexString = request.getParameter("st");  // get the index pages    
%>
```

I am always getting the "" (empty string) for 'startIndexString ' value.

Please help. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are tou using MVCPortlet? do you pass the 'st' parameter in the renderRequest, in your render function ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code snippet

```
<%
    int startIndex = 3;
%>

<portlet:renderURL var="nextURL">
     <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/demo/view.jsp" />
     <portlet:param name="st" value="<%=String.valueOf(startIndex) %>"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

HTH